# How to color diagonal list item of recyclerview grid layout manager of span count of 2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, logic

I need to color list item diagonally of grid layout manager of span count 2

for example:

- color 0th, 3rd,4th,7th, 8th and so on position in One color
- color 1th, 2nd, 5th, 6th, 9th,10th and so on position in another color

Please provide any logic for this for coloring item of recyclerview

corresponding image

[image]

In this picture item next to hindi is has to color as item english is colored

Comment: If you want a pattern to repeats every 4 positions just use `position` provided 
 during `onBindViewHolder` calculate modulo 4 of it and use result to apply the colors.

Comment: my question is how to color 0th, 3rd,4th,7th, 8th and so on position in One color and rest is in other color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pawel mentioned in the comment, you can add the following logic in your `onBindViewHolder` function:

```kotlin
val mod = adapterPosition % 4
val backgroundColor = if(mod == 0 || mod == 3) color1 else color2
// Set this color to your view
```

Here `color1` will be set for elements at index 0, 3, 4, 7, 8, ... and `color2` will be set for the remaining positions.

Comment: This is the exact answer for my question thanks a lot